# Fuse 6.2 Integration with Websphere MQ 8.0.0.3

Tags: ibm-mq, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am attempting to link the newest Jboss Fuse 6.2 with the newest Websphere MQ 8.0.0.3.

I am having issues where the application gives up waiting for the service:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) on project WebsphereThroughput: null: MojoExecutionException: InvocationTargetException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext) -> [Help 1]

I have added a ConnectionFactory to my blueprint source:

```
<bean id="wmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="com.ibm.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="transportType" value="1" />
      <property name="hostName" value="<InsertIPAddressOfRemoteWMQServer>"/>
      <property name="port" value="1414"/>
      <property name="queueManager" value="WQM"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

My route is simple and takes a message from a file and inserts it onto a Websphere MQ queue named INPUT:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="file:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test"/>
    <to uri="wmq:queue:INPUT"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

Finally I have added the following IBM dependencies inside of the pom.xml file (As well as installing them onto my local maven repository):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I would appreciate any help as this has been stumping me for a while now. Thank you.

Stack Trace:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Camel Blueprint Route 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\test\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:manifest (bundle-manifest) @ test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ test ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:bundle (default-bundle) @ test ---
[WARNING] Bundle org.Fuse.Testing:test:bundle:1.0.0 : Instructions in Private-Package, or -testpackages that are never used: org\.Fuse\.Testing\.test\..*|org\.Fuse\.Testing\.test
Classpath: Jar:.,Jar:camel-core,Jar:jaxb-core,Jar:jaxb-impl,Jar:camel-blueprint,Jar:camel-core-xml,Jar:camel-core-osgi,Jar:slf4j-api,Jar:slf4j-log4j12,Jar:log4j,Jar:camel-test-blueprint,Jar:camel-test,Jar:camel-core,Jar:org.apache.aries.blueprint,Jar:org.apache.aries.util,Jar:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl,Jar:org.apache.aries.proxy.api,Jar:de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework,Jar:pax-swissbox-tinybundles,Jar:ops4j-base-lang,Jar:ops4j-base-io,Jar:ops4j-base-monitors,Jar:ops4j-base-store,Jar:pax-swissbox-bnd,Jar:bndlib,Jar:commons-logging,Jar:junit,Jar:hamcrest-core,Jar:org.apache.felix.configadmin,Jar:org.apache.felix.fileinstall,Jar:camel-jms,Jar:camel-spring,Jar:spring-aop,Jar:aopalliance,Jar:spring-jms,Jar:spring-core,Jar:spring-messaging,Jar:spring-context,Jar:spring-expression,Jar:spring-tx,Jar:spring-beans

[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) @ test >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:manifest (bundle-manifest) @ test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) @ test <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] Using org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main to initiate a CamelContext
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] Starting Camel ...
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] MainSupport                    INFO  Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-620133 starting
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator starting
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator started
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  No quiesce support is available, so blueprint components will not participate in quiesce operations
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintContainerImpl         INFO  Bundle test is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint]
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BeanRecipe                     WARN  Object to be destroyed is not an instance of UnwrapperedBeanHolder, type: null
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-620133 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-620133 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime not started
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-620133 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.016 seconds
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintContainerImpl         ERROR Unable to start blueprint container for bundle test
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate components
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:672)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/ConnectionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.findMatchingConstructors(BeanRecipe.java:509)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:327)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:806)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:668)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  Test bundle headers: Bundle-ManifestVersion=2, Bundle-Name=System Bundle, Bundle-SymbolicName=de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework, Bundle-Vendor=kalpatec, Bundle-Version=0.2.1
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterLoader], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-spring [28], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-spring
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormatResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle.EventHook], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.felix.cm.PersistenceManager], bundle: org.apache.felix.configadmin [25], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.configadmin
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterLoader], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-spring [28], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-spring
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin], bundle: org.apache.felix.configadmin [25], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.configadmin
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService], bundle: org.apache.felix.fileinstall [26], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.fileinstall
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.startlevel.StartLevel], bundle: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework [0], symbolicName: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory], bundle: org.apache.felix.fileinstall [26], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.fileinstall
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.services.ParserService], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint [6], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin], bundle: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework [0], symbolicName: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [13], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterLoader], bundle: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework [0], symbolicName: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-spring [28], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-spring
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactInstaller], bundle: org.apache.felix.fileinstall [26], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.fileinstall
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.proxy.ProxyManager], bundle: org.apache.aries.proxy.impl [15], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.proxy.impl
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint [6], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-jms [27], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-jms
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle test
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator stopping
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator stopped
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           INFO  Deleting work directory target/bundles/1442417582122
[ERROR] *************************************
[ERROR] Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main
[ERROR] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:488)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:240)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:202)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.doStart(Main.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:354)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.main(Main.java:81)
    ... 6 more
[ERROR] *************************************
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.478 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-16T11:33:32-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/458M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) on project test: null: MojoExecutionException: InvocationTargetException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Have you checked the error log of the queue manager? Are you using the connection factory with the property values quoted?

Comment: @Attila Repasi No errors on the side of the queue manager. The values are quoted in the connection factory.

I am adding the full stack trace above as well as I noticed there is another exception regarding javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.

Comment: Sorry I mean, are you using the values you have included in your question?

Comment: @Attila Repasi Yes I am minus the hostname which is an ipaddress

Comment: I'd like to provide some clarification on this thread.  Please be aware that I am the Americas support lead for Red Hat supporting JBoss Fuse, and IBM MQ.

Comment: I'd like to provide some clarification on this thread.  Please be aware that I am the Americas support lead for Red Hat supporting JBoss Fuse, and IBM MQ.  JBoss Fuse 6.2 supports JMS 1.1, while JBoss Fuse 6.3 supports JMS 2.0.  These products are OSGi based and you should be using the bundles in the /opt/mqm/java/lib/OSGi directory.  As IBM MQ 7.5 is JMS 1.1 and MQ 8 is JMS 2.0, you must use the MQ 7.5 bundles on Fuse 6.2.  Note that the com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_7.5.0.X.jar bundle contains the JMS API spec.  Do not deploy this bundle on Fuse as it conflicts with the Fuse JMS bundle.

Answer (score 3):

After many different possible solutions I have found what works:

First - I did not have the correct version of the .jar files. The .jars must be the same version as the MQ you are using. (in my case I should have been using 8.0.0.2)

Second - The jars you need are : com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar, fscontext.jar, providerutil.jar, and jms.jar

Third - The jars must be imported through Maven. The .jars cannot be added to the classpath as Fuse does not know to look here.

Finally - The bean looked like this:

```
<bean id="websphere" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="transportType" value="1" />
            <property name="hostName" value="IPAddress"/>
            <property name="port" value="1414"/>
            <property name="queueManager" value="WQM"/>
            <property name="channel" value="SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

This article could be usefull for you:
http://www.soapassion.com/jboss/integrate-ibm-websphere-mq-8-jboss-fuse-6-3/

If you're using Fuse in Karaf container, then you'll need an osgi component. If you have that components, then Fuse (Karaf) will recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

You can access IBM MQ 8 with JBoss Fuse 6.2 via the IBM MQ 7.5 client code.  IBM MQ 8 is JMS 2.0, while JBoss Fuse 6.2 is JMS 1.1 based.  IBM certifies the 7.5 client code against the 8 broker.

Comment: I have reviewed the previous comments and thought that I would add some clarification.